# c program output explanation

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I found this piece of code somewhere on the net. The output of the program is 
string
string
string
Can someone please explain me why the first secon and third printf statements printing the same output even though the arguments for them are different?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char a[2][3][3] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g'};
printf("%s\n", *a);
printf("%s\n", a);
printf("%s\n", **a);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chris the array has total size 18 and is initialised with 6 elements, so all later elements will be `0`.

Comment: @chris I know that. But I haven't written the code myself I found it on the net.

Comment: @ecatmur, Oops, that's right. For some reason I thought all of the elements were being set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this is 3 dimensional array (array of array of arrays), `*a`, `a`, and `**a` all refer to the same address.  The type isn't correct for `printf()` for the first two, however it will be interpreted as a flat `char *` string in all cases.  If you turn up the warnings on your compiler, you should see some about the format string and types not matching.

Keep in mind that `*a` is like `a[0]` and `**a` is like `a[0][0]`. That may make it easier to see why they reference the same address.

Answer (score 2):

You're treating a `char (*)[3]` and a `char (*)[3][3]` as a `char *`.  Since they point to the same address, and (in this case) they have the same in-memory representation, they're being read the same as a `char *` pointing to that address.

This is undefined behaviour; don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

lets see how `char a[2][3][3]` is layed out in memory. In my machine its like this:

```
0x7fffffffe220: 0x73    0x74    0x72    0x69    0x6e    0x67    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe228: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe230: 0x00    0x00
```

Its only natural because all arrays are actually linear. What these dimensions means, comes in handy with array indices like `a[i][j][k]`. But from memory's point of view its all just a tricky way to calculate offset from a base address.

Now because you have defined it as three dimensional array, you may want to know how C will treat this array after initialization :

```
{{{0x73, 0x74, 0x72}, {0x69, 0x6e, 0x67}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}, {{0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}}
```

Now lets see what we have here...

Printf is called to print a sting and passed with a address. So what printf will do, is to grab that address, and try  to **until it sees a null**

Every call to `print` the same thing because :

```
(gdb) x/10xb **a
0x7fffffffe220: 0x73    0x74    0x72    0x69    0x6e    0x67    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe228: 0x00    0x00
(gdb) x/10xb *a
0x7fffffffe220: 0x73    0x74    0x72    0x69    0x6e    0x67    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe228: 0x00    0x00
(gdb) x/10xb a
0x7fffffffe220: 0x73    0x74    0x72    0x69    0x6e    0x67    0x00    0x00
0x7fffffffe228: 0x00    0x00
```

Lastly a word of advice, do to code this way. If you're smart enough, do everything by pointers alone. But its more error prone. So although underlying layer will treat pointers and arrays almost interchangeably, you stick with what you have started with. Treat things like pointers if can manipulate stuffs by your hand. Treat stuffs like arrays if you want a more strict manipulation by indices.